# Eclipse Verify Launch Attributes

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When debugging my app, on my Mac OS X Snow Leopard with Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3, in Eclipse when I hit start or debug the compiler sticks on "Verifying Launch Attributes 57%" for an extended period of time, about a minute - two and when it hits a break point it takes a while for the IDE to put the green line at the break point but you can see that it has stopped running the app.

The same code and everything worked fine a couple weeks ago, prior to getting Update 3 of Java from Apple but I can't really find a way to go back to Update 2 to see if that is the issue. Anyone have any thoughts on what could be causing this???

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Are you using IvyDE? I removed ivy resolution before launch, and now my junit tests run without annoying delays.

- Window -> Preferences -> Ivy -> Classpath
- Uncheck "Resolve before launch"

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable IPv6. [See this blog post](http://blog.pdark.de/2012/05/10/eclipse-suddenly-takes-long-to-start-unit-tests/) by me how to do that.

Comment: I followed the instructions from here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/18097613#18097613 and the problem still exists.

Comment: Run `netstat -ptn|grep eclipse` when Eclipse hangs to see which IP-address/transport it uses.

Comment: I didn't see any process listed, tried with sudo also. Perhaps it is hanging for a different reason.. it definitely hangs for less than 30 seconds (more like 15 seconds) in my case, which is still a nuisance, when the test itself takes only a second to execute and I am quickly trying out changes.

Comment: @haridsv: In that case, try to create a thread dump while Eclipse hangs, for example with `jstack` which should be part of your Java install.

Comment: It seems to be taking a lot of time in org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXVMInstallType.getDefaultSystemLibrarySource() calling File.isFile(), perhaps in a loop. Is it searching for src.zip (which I don't have)?

Comment: The only reason why this could be slow is when your Java VM is installed on a network drive :-/

Comment: It is installed locally, on an SSD drive. I am going to download src.zip and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It really shouldn't. Check which paths Eclipse will look at on the "Installed JREs" preferences page. If "ls <path>" in a console doesn't hang, then Eclipse shouldn't hang either. There could be a virus scanner that is blocking access, though.

Comment: I don't now if it was a virus scanner, but I got the src.zip and attached it to the classes.jar going from the installer JREs page and the problem is now gone. Very strange!